# AlertDialog isn't showing up

Tags: java, android

An AlertDialog doesn't show up when I enter numbers that are bigger than 100 in one case and doesn't show up when I enter numbers bigger than 20 , in the other case. Other doubt that I have is ,when I click the button and there is no text the app just closes .
Here is the code for `onClick`the button.

```
    contador = 0;
    sum = 0;


    {
    add_grade.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                        adicionador = Integer.valueOf(grade.getText().toString());
                    add_grade.setOnClickListener(
                            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    if(Metodo_de_medicao==20 && adicionador>20){
                                        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Automatico2.this).create();
                                        alertDialog.setTitle("Erro");
                                        alertDialog.setMessage("Não insira valores maiores que 20");
                                        alertDialog.show();
                                        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                                    }

                                                });
                                        adicionador=-adicionador;
                                        contador=-1;
                                    }
                                    if(Metodo_de_medicao==100 && adicionador>100){
                                        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Automatico2.this).create();
                                        alertDialog.setTitle("Erro");
                                        alertDialog.setMessage("Não insira valores maiores que 100");
                                        alertDialog.show();
                                        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                                    }

                                                });
                                        adicionador=-adicionador;
                                        contador=-1;}
                                    sum = sum + adicionador;
                                    contador++;
                                    grade.setText("");
                                    grade.requestFocus();

                                }
                            }

                    );


                        sum = sum + adicionador;
                        contador++;
                        grade.setText("");
                        grade.requestFocus();

                }
            }

    );}
```

Comment: Catch `NumberFormatException`s. Also what the hell are you trying to ask?

Comment: Im just trying to when Método_de_medicao==100 and adicionador is more than 100 , do that alert dialog, AND other if is when Método_de_medicao==20 and adicionador is more than 20, do that alert dialog

Comment: Do you know a easier way to do it ?

Comment: `(A==100 && B>100) || (A==20 && B>20)`

Comment: Oh i have found the error, the alertDialog.show should be after the .setButton and I had two onClickListeners My bad